# In objective c can a class essentially delete itself?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

In objective c, suppose I have an object `Obj` stored in a NSMutableArray, and the array's pointer to it is the only strong pointer to `Obj` in the entire program.  Now suppose I call a method on `Obj` and I run this method in another thread.  In this method, if `Obj` sets the pointer for itself equal to `nil` will it essentially delete itself? (Because there will be no more strong pointers left)  I suspect the answer is no, but why?  If this does work, is it bad coding practice (I assume its not good coding, but is it actually bad?)

Comment: Setting `self` to `nil` will not delete anything.

Comment: Not setting self to nil, but setting the pointer in the array that points to self, equal to nil

Comment: you mean the instance of a class, not the class itself? If yes, you should edit the question!

Comment: I'm interpreting your question to mean "Can an object be deallocated while it is in the middle of executing one of its methods?" Is that correct?

Comment: My question is what happens if an object removes the last remaining pointer to it in the middle of one of its methods? And is this bad coding practice?

Comment: @Nosrettap With automatic reference counting this is impossible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that an object would be in a position to cause its own release/deallocation if your code is designed properly. So yes, the situation you describe is indicative of bad coding practice, and can in fact cause the program to crash. Here is an example:

```
@interface Widget : NSObject
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *array;
@end

@implementation Widget

@synthesize array;

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [array addObject:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"Deallocating!");
    [array release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)removeSelf
{
    NSLog(@"%d", [array count]);
    [array removeObject:self];
    NSLog(@"%d", [array count]);
}
@end
```

and then this code is in another class:

```
Widget *myWidget = [[Widget alloc] init];
[myWidget release];  // WHOOPS!
[myWidget removeSelf];
```

The second call to NSLog in `removeSelf` will cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS due to the fact that `array` has been deallocated at that point and can't have methods called on it.

There are at least a couple mistakes here. The one that ultimately causes the crash is the fact that whatever class is creating and using the `myWidget` object releases it before it is finished using it (to call removeSelf). Without this mistake, the code would run fine. However, MyWidget shouldn't have an instance variable that creates a strong reference to itself in the first place, as this creates a retain cycle. If someone tried to release `myWidget` without first calling `removeSelf`, nothing would be deallocated and you'd probably have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

If your back-pointer is weak (which it should be since a class should never try to own it's owner, you will end up with a retain-cycle) and you remove the strong pointer from the array the object will be removed from the heap. No strong pointers = removed from memory.

You can always test this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a class to bring to a situation where its deleted, the best practice is to first retain/autorelease it and then make the situation happen. In this case the class won't be deleted in a middle of its method, but only afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can say it *might be* bad coding practice, depending on how you do it. There are ways you could arrange to do it safely, or probably safely.

So let's assume we have a global:

```
NSMutableArray *GlobalStore;
```

One approach is to remove yourself as your final action:

```
- (void) someMethod
{
   ...
   [GlobalStore removeObject:self];
}
```

As this is the final action there should be no future uses of `self` and all should be well, probably...

Other options include scheduling the removal with a time delay of 0 - which means it will fire next time around the run loop (only works of course if you have a run loop, which in a thread you may not). This should always be safe.

You can also have an object keep a reference to itself, which produces a cycle and so will keep it alive. When its ready to die it can nil out its own reference, if there are no other references and that is a final action (or a scheduled action by another object) then the object is dead.